# How declared a CONDENSED NUMERIC Variable in COBOL

Tags: cobol

My COBOL problem is:
That i have data in the table at data base : my data is  :
Z-ZYSR-MONTAN(IZYSR) that have a format : NOT NULL NUMBER(11,2) .

so I have a program that I need to move my data in one variable "H-ZYSR-MONTAN " and after I will move this in one colonne Z8 when I compile I obtained Excel with data in the different colonne.

my question how to declare the variable to obtain the good result?

I do this but I can't obtient the right resultat:
My data in the beging:
2223,55
-10,98
-1,08
82,61

variables that I declare:
 
*05  H-ZYSR-MONTAN           PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3.*

** Taux horaire formation
            05  W-Z18                  PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3.
            05  FILLER                 PIC X(001) VALUE ';'.*

The code:

```
    ALIM-WZ18 SECTION.
             MOVE Z-ZYSR-NOMBRE TO IZYSR.
             MOVE ZERO TO H-ZYSR-MONTAN.

          IF Z-ZYSR-NOMBRE > ZERO
             PERFORM VARYING IZYSR FROM Z-ZYSR-NOMBRE BY -1 UNTIL
                             IZYSR = ZERO
                IF Z-ZYSR-CODRUB(IZYSR) = 'THF'
                   MOVE Z-ZYSR-MONTAN(IZYSR) TO
                        H-ZYSR-MONTAN

                   MOVE ZERO TO IZYSR
                END-IF
             END-PERFORM
               MOVE H-ZYSR-MONTAN TO W-Z18
               END-IF.
```

The resultat that i obtain is like this  :

Z18
€
" "
0
0
@

0
P
@

I never obtain the same like:
2223,55
-10,98
-1,08
82,61

Comment: what is the hex value of that? COMP fields are stored 2 digits per byte. So if you try to display it, it will often look like garbage even if it is correct.

Comment: My initial data is Z-ZYSR-MONTAN(IZYSR) : its like this a lot of differents value :12225,50 ; 150,52  ; -20,08 ; -1542,69 .... so how can decalarte this variable in COBOL

Comment: that doesn't clarify. I wan't to know the hex value of your output.

Comment: can you see my answer

Comment: that should not be an answer and still doesn't add any clarifications. also why did you insert CSS?

Comment: u can do run i do table to be clear

Comment: can you see this https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1940330/autres-langages/autres-langages/cobol/numerique-condense-cobol/#post10762734

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the problem, you only need to change the formatting of `W-Z18` from `PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3` to `PIC -(12),99`, as shown below.
Does this help?

```
   environment division.
   configuration section.
   special-names.
       decimal-point is comma.
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   1 filler.
    2 test-values.
     3 pic s9(11)v99 comp-3 value 2223,55.
     3 pic s9(11)v99 comp-3 value -10,98.
     3 pic s9(11)v99 comp-3 value -1,08.
     3 pic s9(11)v99 comp-3 value 82,61.
    2 filler redefines test-values.
     3 test-value comp-3 pic s9(11)v99 occurs 4.

   1 W-Z18 PIC -(12),99.

   1 i binary pic 9(4).
   procedure division.
   begin.
       perform varying i from 1 by 1 until i > 4
           move test-value (i) to W-Z18
           display W-Z18
       end-perform
       stop run
       .
```

Results:

```
        2223,55
         -10,98
          -1,08
          82,61
```

Comment: Yes i put  decimal-point is comma.and after i put my variable H-ZYSR-MONTAN with this PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3 because my  montan its a data number(11,2) but i have a lot of data for a lot of employees. I need to move MONTAN (data ) in  H-ZYSR-MONTAN  and after move  H-ZYSR-MONTAN  to W-Z18. so yes you understant what i want but with a lot of data

Comment: so i used like this : H-ZYSR-MONTAN with this PIC S9(11)V9(2)  COMP-3 and  W-Z18 PIC -(12),99 , i get the right resultat

Comment: @gnad - Guessing from the various parts of the question and comments, it appears that data is transferred as follows: SQL Data Base --> COBOL --> File FICSOR --> Excel. The semi-colon `;` is used as a separator in Excel and the invalid data like `Z18 € " " 0 0 @` was shown in Excel. Is that correct?

Comment: i have juste a question why u used this format PIC -(12),99. for Z18?

Comment: See [Floating insertion editing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rlddeief.htm) for more information. I used 12 rather than 11 to allow for the sign position. In effect `-(12),99` is the same as `------------,99`.